# Does JXCore protect source code securely?

Tags: node.js, jxcore

I'm planning to use JXCore for two reasons.

1. to make an executable file with no dependencies for my Node.js project
2. to protect my javascript source code

First purpose is worked fine, but I can't ensure second thing.
Is it secure from Reverse Engineering if I use JXCore for my project and make a executable file?
Can someone read my source code(javascript) if he broke my executable file?
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JXcore is an open source project, so it cannot guarantee source code protection.  The source files are not really kept encrypted inside the exe file (native package) - they are only compressed. The packaging algorithm is visible from the source code so people may look into it. Nevertheless it may not be a straightforward task, so probably not anyone can do it. But still, although I haven't see any extracting tools as of yet, it doesn't mean that they will not arrive at some point.

But you may consider adding an extra difficulty layer and obfuscate your javascript files before creating your exe.